# How to install Indy on Delphi 10.3 Rio?

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-10.3-rio

The help says "You can use GetIt Package Manager to discover and install additional third-party software onto RAD Studio." but Indy is not available in GetIt[image]

I dowloaded newest files from Github. I run the Fullc_Rio.bat file then opened Indy260.groupproj but when compiling I got:

```
[Fatal Error] Cannot compile package 'IndySystem260' which is currently required by Delphi 10.3.
```

Comment: Indy is already installed in Rio during the product installation. It's an integral part of much of the RTL and FMX/VCL functionality. It's not available through GetIt because there's no need for it to be; it's already installed in all versions of Delphi.

Comment: @KenWhite "*It's not available through GetIt because there's no need for it to be*" - that is not why Indy is not in GetIt. The main reason is because Indy's install is a bit complicated for C++ support, which doesn't lend itself well to GetIt. Getting Indy into GetIt is actually on the todo list (https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/134). And I would not say that Indy is "an integral part of much of the RTL and FMX/VCL functionality", because it is not. SOME functionality, like DataSnap, uses Indy, but Embarcadero has been favoring their own cross-platform tech for awhile now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indy is already installed in Rio during the product installation. It's used in parts of the RTL. It's already installed in all versions of Delphi.

If you open a new VCL or FMX application, click on a form to activate the designer, and go to the component palette, and enter *TId* in the search box, you can find the Indy related component pages in the palette.

Answer (score 6):

Indy comes pre-installed in every IDE version, and has been for a very long time.

However, if you want to install a newer version than what Embarcadero ships, you have to first remove the pre-installed version.  This is mentioned in Indy's [installation notes](http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx):

> All package names are followed by X0 (where X0 is your Delphi/C++Builder/RAD Studio product version).
>
> ...
>
> If Indy 10 is already installed, it needs to be uninstalled first:
>
> - Remove the pre-compiled design-time BPL files - dclIndyCoreX0.bpl and dclIndyProtocolsX0.bpl - from the IDE via the "Components > Install Packages" dialog.
> - Delete all of the existing binaries - IndySystemX0.*, (dcl)IndyCoreX0.*, and (dcl)IndyProtocolsX0.*
> - Delete any Indy 10 source files, if present.
> - Be sure to check for files in the IDE's \bin, \lib, and \source folders, \Indy subfolders, and OS system folders.
>
> ...
>
> You can either:
>
> - Use the command-line FULLD#.BAT script that corresponds to your Delphi version.
> - Open the individual DPK files in the IDE and compile them, in the following order:
>
> 1. IndySystemX0.dpk (in Lib\System)
> 2. IndyCoreX0.dpk (in Lib\Core)
> 3. IndyProtocolsX0.dpk (in Lib\Protocols)
> 4. dclIndyCoreX0.dpk (in Lib\Core)
> 5. dclIndyProtocolsX0.dpk (in Lib\Protocols)
>
> ...

Refer to the [installation notes](http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx) for full instructions.

---

**UPDATE**: the installation notes have been moved to Indy's [GitHub repo](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/):

[Updating Indy](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/)

Comment: can you link the full installation notes from other source ? the link is broken. And Do you know what´s can happen with Delphi 10.3 Rio ? i have tryed but my IDE had some pre-compiled packges broken and come crazy and frozen when compiling. I´m reinstalling the IDE to try again and i want to do as the installation notes says.

Comment: @JoaoIshiwatari https://www.indyproject.org/2021/02/10/links-to-old-indy-website-pages-are-currently-broken/ contains a link to an archived copy of the install instructions

Comment: Is 'Indy' the new version of what was known as Indy9 in the Delphi 7 days?

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill yes. That was Indy version 9. Indy is now at version 10